# Prevent website restart when create new pages asp.net

Tags: asp.net, restart

I have code to dynamic create a new page in my asp.net website, and its work great. But when i create new page and go to that page first load is quite long 20+ second  this because probably when i create new page all website restart?

**How do I prevent to my application restarts every time I create a new page?**

II7

This is just a sample code to see how I create new pages, code is not the same but similar :

```
string fielName = Server.MapPath("~/file.aspx");               
// create a writer and open the file
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fielName);

// write a line of text to the file
tw.WriteLine(@"<%@ Page Language=""C#"" AutoEventWireup=""true"" CodeFile=""file.aspx.cs"" Inherits=""file"" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">

<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"">
<head runat=""server"">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id=""form1"" runat=""server"">
    <div>    
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
");

// close the stream
tw.Close();


tw = new StreamWriter(fielName + ".cs");

// write a line of text to the file
tw.WriteLine(@"using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

public partial class file : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Response.Write(""new File "");   
  }
}
");

// close the stream
tw.Close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by creating the page ? You are creating new aspx file ?

Comment: I already posted question on this forum, you can see... But I did not come up with an answer  ...http://forums.asp.net/t/1903473.aspx/1?Prevent+website+restart+when+I+create+new+pages+file+asp+net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent application pool recycle when creating new aspx files, recompiling these aspx eventually requires application pool recycle, so IMO you got a good answers on that forum.

To put it shortly, you are doing it wrong. There is no need to create pages on the disk, your code behind and markup will produce different pages based on data from database.

You have to change that because that way this will NOT work.

For example if you have TextBox in markup :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDataFromDB" runat="Server"/>
```

And then in code behind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
  txtDataFromDB.Text = GetDataFromDatabase();
}
```

Your page will show different content according to data you get from DB.

Comment: Hvala sto si izmenio, nisam objavljivao ranije na ovom forumu pa nisam znao kako da to uguram u kod, znam da je bolje napraviti jednu stranu pa bazu filtrirati queri-ja, ali kad sam ovo radio potpuno sam zaboravio za problem restartovanja sajta prilikom kreiranj nove strane, vidim da postoji nacin da se "iskljuci" monitoring foldera prilikom menjanja istog ili u njemu nesto poput ovog primera...  ili da krenem ja to ispocetka i da bacim ceo mesec posla :(   http://beweb.pbworks.com/w/page/30073098/Prevent%20app%20restarts%20and%20site%20downtime%20when%20deploying%20files

Comment: nemam pojma, ali bojim se da tim putem ćeš naići samo na probleme, probaj onda barem proizvoditi obične html stranice a ne aspx pa ti se neće runtime restartati

Comment: Ipak cu Kenuti ispocetka, jedna lekcija vise!

Answer (score 0):

You use the lifecylce ?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GenerateWebsite();                              
        }
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252%28v=vs.100%29.aspx -> Have you read this allready ?

Comment: I already posted question on this forum, you can see... But I did not come up with an answer  ...http://forums.asp.net/t/1903473.aspx/1?Prevent+website+restart+when+I+create+new+pages+file+asp+net

Comment: Yeah sorry, but I dont really get what you mean there. When do you build your website ? After an event e.g. klicking on a button ? Or just when your website starts ? I need some more CodeBehind...

Comment: I don't built website, i built new file/page on existing site after an event.

Comment: Ah okay, Antonios explanation showed me what you mean. At this point i cant help you sorry.